# Is it true that a "dekoriert"-sign means that naked women are dancing?

Tags: germany, switzerland, austria, carnival-mardi-gras

During carnival in German-speaking Europe, there are a lot of bars that have a sign at the front door stating "dekoriert", which means decorated. However, when you go inside, there are no decorations related to carnival visible, and the drinks are very expensive. Instead, you can find naked women dancing in there.

[image]
(from [flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/kecko/96387320/))

So my question is: Is this just a coincidence or is the "dekoriert"-sign a hidden message for naked girls?

Comment: Interesting, never seen it. Do you happen to have any photograph?

Comment: I was looking for one, but couldn't find it. When I'm there the next time, I try to take one.

Comment: Perhaps also relevant: [German language Stack Exchange](http://german.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: This question really needs one or more of these tags: [tag:german], [tag:language], [tag:terminology]

Comment: Was that the bar where you saw the girls? Which city was that?

Comment: @uncovery - note that I added the picture, since RoflcoptrException had been unable to find one.  Unless I got very lucky with my google searches, I doubt it's the same place :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I thought it's time to finally answer my own question. After a lot of research, I could find to newspaper article that state that the "dekortiert" sign indicates that some nudism might be expected. Unfortunately the articles are only available in German, but here they are:

http://www.tagblatt.ch/ostschweiz/stgallen/stadtstgallen/tb-ag/Beizen-locken-mit-Reizen;art197,2862487

http://www.tagblatt.ch/ostschweiz/stgallen/rorschach/tb-ot08/Fasnacht-zwischen-Dessous-und-Deko;art2889,1675108

The articles also say that this is a tradition that is actually dying and you see less and less such bars.

Comment: Yeah yeah you "thought" it was time to answer...

Comment: Apparently there is a local (but waning) custom called "Beizenfasnacht" in eastern Switzerland where some bars have salacious decoration and scantily clad (but probably not nude) serving girls. It doesn't seem to be a hidden code as is implied in the question, though.

Comment: Sorry but I have to contradict your statement. The articles you list say that there are "dekoriert" bars that ALSO show nudity. But there are enough of those which are marked "dekoriert" that do not show nudity. While the "dekoriert" might be a prerequisite for carnival events that show nudity (why would you make a carnival event without decorating your bar to create the mood), but there is NO direct consequence of nudity out of a "dekoriert" sign. the "might be expected" as you say it is as much a link as saying that "if you walk into a bar, you might have a drink".

Answer (score 17):

The sign "dekoriert" in Germany and also in Switzerland means that there will be Fasnacht/Fasching/Karneval decoration in the venue, mostly in Restaurants and Bars. Only decoration - nothing else implied. You will find those signs on the most boring and conservative countryside family restaurants just as well as downtown bars that open at 23:00 and close at 4:00.

These signs do not indicate any price changes or any kind of events happening in the bar. Unless there are city-wide carnival activities on special days of the year, you should expect there to be additional information when there is a special (public) event related to carnival. This can include live music or shows. Some parts of these shows might look to some like "[naked girls](http://www.myheimat.de/friedberg/freizeit/orcc-friedberg-startet-mit-festlicher-gala-in-den-fasching-2013-d2482417.html)", but they are more clothed than the actually topless or even completely naked girls in some Brazilian carnival parades.

What to expect inside a bar during carnival goes pretty much under the same principles as outside of carnival: If there is a special event, they might charge extra. If they do not show fully naked or topless girls normally, the chances are very slim they would do so during carnival either.